# gRPC service options syntax

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I've seen this syntax in proto files:

```
service A {
    option (...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

What is it used for? I can't find it on the official documentation, either...

Comment: Have you had a look [here](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/concepts/)?  I'm not familiar with the option tag for a service definition.  Where did you see this syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, it is custom options found here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#options